# Inline headings in form

Tags: django, django-forms

I'm trying to generate a form using crispy form and would like to have inline headings, e.g.,

**Personal Information**

Name [             ]
Address [              ]

**Comment**

Category [                ]
Message [                  ]

I see that setting the fields using

```
helper = FormHelper()
helper.form_class = 'form-horizontal'
helper.layout = Layout( ... )
```

doesn't produce any heading, but only labels for the fields.

Does anyone know how to integrate headings into a form?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like your are looking for a [`fieldset`](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/fieldset):

> The fieldset element represents a set of form controls optionally
>   grouped under a common name.

Crispy Forms has a layout object for fieldsets wich you can use in this case: [`layout.Fieldset`](http://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.org/en/d-0/api_layout.html#layout.Fieldset)